# How to matlab continue processing while waiting for user input

Tags: matlab, image-processing, input

Suppose we have the following `for` loop:

```
for i=1:100
    % image processing calculation
    % show image to the user and ask for his rating
    rating(i) = input('Enter rating of the shown image\n');
end
```

Obviously, the `input` command will wait for the user input and the `for` loop won't continue until the user has provided his input. The image processing code I'm running in the `for` loop is time consuming so I'd like to know if there's a way to make MATLAB continue calculations - in the background - for the following loop iteration while waiting for the user's input.

Comment: Why not ask for the ratings after the `for` loop, in their own `for` loop?

Comment: The calculations are independent of the value of rating. Putting the rating before 'for' loop is not logical, because my code does a certain processing on an image from a set of 100 images and then asks the user for his rating.

Comment: If I ask the user for the rating after the for loop is done processing, i will be wasting time running the for loop on all images while the user is waiting. That's why I went to ask for the rating by the end of every iteration

Comment: Then I suggest you to open a new figure for each iteration (you can limit the maximum number of open figures). Show the image inside the figure along a `text box` for the user to enter the rating. Whenever the user wants to rate, he/she enters the rating in the `text box` and when closes the figure and the rating could be saved into `rating(i)`.

Comment: look at callback functions instead of for loops : http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-and-executing-callback-functions.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the idea I mentioned in my comment.

```
num_im = 3; % Number of images

% Initialize
rating = zeros(num_im,1);
fig = zeros(num_im,1);
txt = zeros(num_im,1);

% Main loop
for i = 1:num_im
    % image processing calculation
    pause(1); % a dummy calculation
    % Open a figure
    fig(i) = figure('Name', ['Image #' num2str(i)],...
        'CloseRequestFcn', [... % read the text edit
        'temp = str2double(get(txt(' num2str(i) '), ''String'')); ',...
        'if isnan(temp), errordlg(''Please enter the rating.''); ',... % Error if invalid
        'else, rating(' num2str(i) ') = temp; delete(fig(' num2str(i) ')); end']);

    subplot(2,1,1, 'position', [0 0.5 1 0.5]);

    % Show your image
    [im, map] = imread('trees.tif');
    imshow(im, map);
    % Text edit
    txt(i) = uicontrol('Units','Normalized',...
        'Style','edit',...
        'Position', [0.3 0.2 0.4 0.2]); 
end
```

Make sure to **click somewhere else** after you enter the ratings so that the `text box` detects your input.

It will store all the ratings in `rating` matrix.

However this does not **limit the number of open figures**.
Refer to the **Edit** if you want to limit them.

---

## Edit

To limit the number of opened figures. I suggest you to put all the images after calculation in a Queue and set a timer to ask the user rating in the background until all the ratings are asked.

### Main.m

```
num_im = 4; % Number of images
max_num_figs = 2; % maximum number of open figures

% Initialize
rating = zeros(num_im,1);
fig = zeros(num_im,1);
txt = zeros(num_im,1);
show_idx = 0; % Number of shown images
Calc_idx = 0; % Number of images in Queue
num_open_figs = 0; % number of open figures

Queue = cell(num_im, 1);
% Main loop

% Start a timer for asking the user rating in background
tmr = timer('ExecutionMode', 'fixedRate',...
    'Period', 0.5, 'TimerFcn', 'tmr_callback');
start(tmr);

for k = 1:num_im
    % image processing calculation
    pause(1); % a dummy calculation

    % Put the image and its data into a Queue ith
    [im, map] = imread('trees.tif');
    Queue{Calc_idx+1} = {im, map};
    Calc_idx = Calc_idx + 1;
end
```

### tmr_callback.m

```
% Create a GUI if there is any unshown images in the Queue
% and if open figures are less than maximum number of figures
if show_idx < Calc_idx && num_open_figs < max_num_figs
    num_open_figs = num_open_figs + 1;
    show_idx = show_idx + 1; % Number of shown images
    % Open a figure
    fig(show_idx) = figure('Name', ['Image #' num2str(show_idx)],...
        'CloseRequestFcn', [...
        'temp = str2double(get(txt(' num2str(show_idx) '), ''String'')); ',... % Read the text edit
        'if isnan(temp), errordlg(''Please enter the rating.''); ',... % Error if invalid
        'else, rating(' num2str(show_idx) ') = temp; delete(fig(' num2str(show_idx) ')); ',...
        'num_open_figs  = num_open_figs - 1; end']);

    subplot(2,1,1, 'position', [0 0.5 1 0.5]);
    imshow(Queue{show_idx}{:});
    % Text edit
    txt(show_idx) = uicontrol('Units','Normalized',...
        'Style','edit',...
        'Position', [0.3 0.2 0.4 0.2]);
    % turn off the timer if all ratings are asked.
    if (show_idx == num_im)
        stop(tmr);
    end
end
```

I also suggest to write the data(rating) into a file after the user enters each of them. You can use [`dlmwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html) for example.

Comment: This is pretty much what I need. How do you suggest I limit the maximum number of simultaneously open figures ? Let's say I want to have 3 figures open at the same time, then the program pauses from running until one of the figures is closed. I think keeping a variable of the number of opened figures can come into handy but I don't know how to set a maximum limit ...